# How to use auto form and collection2 package for validation data type with Decimal Number in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I would like to use and validate Decimal data type in meteor with aldeed:autoform and aldeed:collecion2.
For Example I have a simpleSchema and I want to use Decimal like:

```
   MySchema = new SimpleSchema({
      number: {
        type: Decimal
      }
    });
```

Somebody can help me please!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `type: Number`, `decimal: true`

```
MySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  number: {
    type: Number,
    decimal: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Nps, I had the same problem. The docs weren't particularly helpful, but I stumbled across the answer eventually.